# UPDATE datatype image in SQL-Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, set

I've a table `cSc_Role` with a column `RoleSettings`. 
`RoleSettings` is datatype image.
The Content is something like this: 0x504B030414000000080000000000E637CA2A4

Now I need to update this column for one row.
Like this:

```
UPDATE cSc_Role
SET RoleSettings = '0x343240000000000E637CA2A430500'
WHERE Naming = 'User X'
```

But with binary data it seems like this is not possible to do it with a string.
The other option is, I can provide the image in a temporary .bak file.
And then do an `INSERT INTO`.
But with this solution I've read it is only possible to insert a complete row and not only a column. Or can I insert only a column with insert?

How can I update or insert one image-column in a table?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use convert to varbinary:

```
UPDATE cSc_Role
SET RoleSettings = convert(VARBINARY(MAX),'0x343240000000000E637CA2A430500')
WHERE Naming = 'User X'
```

Comment: this works (u just missed an e in convert). And it converts the given string into hex. So, what I want to copy into RoleSettings is the content from another database, where I copied the content into a textfile. So, I think first I need to convert this content into decimal, and then convert it back with update into hex?

Comment: @user1673665 I'm not sure but maybe you're right. Try it then you will know :)

Answer (score 1):

If above all solution did not work then try to update like below by removing `''` in following ,

```
UPDATE cSc_Role
SET RoleSettings = 0x343240000000000E637CA2A430500
WHERE Naming = 'User X'
```

Also, avoid using these data types (**ntext, text, and image**) in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use ***nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max)*** instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use a hex-literal, x'34....'

```
UPDATE cSc_Role
SET RoleSettings = x'343240000000000E637CA2A430500'
WHERE Naming = 'User X'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But when I try this I get error wrong syntax. I put the letter x before the ' and removed the 0x at the beginning.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (My answer is ANSI SQL compliant...)

Comment: MS SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem on project, you need to provide binary data as hex value, not string. This tool can make you UPDATE or INSERT that you need

[Binary-file-to-sql-hexstring](http://www.motobit.com/util/binary-file-to-sql-hexstring.asp)

It has saved me a lot of man hours.