# Update datatype image column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29816984/update-datatype-image-in-sql-table) but it did not worked for me.

Can anyone please tell me how can I update Datatype `Image` column in `SQL Server 2008 R2.`

***For example,***

```
Update TableName
Set ShowImage = '0xFFD8FFE000104A46494600010101004800480000FFDB0043000604040405040605050609'
WHERE Id =1
```

This is not updating. :(

Please suggest the best and easy way to update the `Image` datatype column.

*Thanks a lot.*

Comment: And, of course, [ntext, tex and image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187993.aspx): "**ntext**, **text**, and **image** data types will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them"

Comment: I'm not going to regurgitate the documentation that I've already given you a link to.

Comment: Sorry @Damien_The_Unbeliever - I have not checked that link. BTW thanks for giving me knowledge. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove `''` in following:

```
Update TableName
Set ShowImage = 0xFFD8FFE000104A46494600010101004800480000FFDB0043000604040405040605050609
where Id =1
```

You have to use `VARBINARY(MAX)` instead of `IMAGE` datatype according to @Damien_The_Unbeliever provided [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187993.aspx).